# Change function arguments based on function in param

Tags: typescript

I have this:

```
type myType = {};

const alpha = (a: string, b:string) => {};
const beta = (a: number, b:number) => {};

export const deploy = async <C extends myType>(toDeployContract: C): C => {}
```

What I want to achieve is that `deploy` accept a function as parameter like that:

```
export const deploy = async <C extends myType>(func: (...args: any[]) => any, toDeployContract: C): C => {}
```

And that doing so, typed `deploy` last parameters automatically based on the passed function. Basically copying every parameter of the pass function.

```
// If alpha function
deploy(alpha, "hello", "world");

// If beta function
deploy(beta, 1, 2);
```

Is that doable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very doable!  You will want your `deploy` function to have a generic type parameter that represents the type of the function.  You can make use of the built-in utility types `Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>` to get the arguments and return type of the function.

I'm not exactly sure how your `C extends myType` comes into play here.  It seems like it's the return type of the function?  You could use `C` as a second generic type parameter but I would recommend leaving it off.

```
export const deploy = async <T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  func: T, 
  ...args: Parameters<T>
): Promise<ReturnType<T>> => {
    return func(...args);
}
```

We say that deploy is based on a type `T` which must be a function.  The first argument of `deploy` is the function `T` and the remaining arguments are the arguments of that function.  `deploy` returns a `Promise` which resolves to the return type of the function `T`.

This allows the usages that you want and gives errors if there is a mismatch between the function and the arguments.

```
// If alpha function
deploy(alpha, "hello", "world");

// If beta function
deploy(beta, 1, 2);

// Expect error
deploy(alpha, 1, 2); // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345)
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/weebXw)

---

If you wanted to use your `C` type, that might look something like this.  We say that `T` is a function which must return a value that is assignable to `C`.

```
type myType = {
    a: string;
};

const alpha = (a: string, b:string) => ({a, b});
const beta = (a: number, b:number) => ({a, b});

export const deploy = async <C extends myType, T extends (...args: any[]) => C>(
  func: T,
  ...args: Parameters<T>
): Promise<C> => {
    return func(...args);
}
```

The `alpha` function is still fine because it returns `{a: string; b: string;}` which extends `{a: string}`.  But you can no longer use the `beta` function because its return type is not assignable to `myType`.

So the `C` parameter allows you to enforce a restriction on what type of function you can `deploy` with.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wj5OkW)